# Repeat a for loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, repeat

I'm just testing the loop in a small dataset. In this case, the loop will be repeated only one time until my condition (both title and url having same lenght) mets.

```
linhas_title <- c(5, 19, 48, 90, 135, 179, 424, 479, 532)
linhas_url <- c(14, 43, 85, 130, 175, 474, 527, 566)

for(i in 1:(length(linhas_title)-1)){
  print(paste("Titulo:",i+1, "e", "Url: ", i))

  if(linhas_title[i+1] - linhas_url[i] < 0) {
    print(paste("Titulo", i, "excluido"))
    linhas_title <- linhas_title[-i]
    break 
  } else print(paste("Titulos e url pareados!"))
}
```

I did not want to break the loop, but restart it. I tried while and repeat functions but without success.

Comment: `while` seems like what you want, so why don't you show us the `while` loop you tried instead of the `for` loop

Comment: Or (less legitimate solution) just substitute `break` with `next`.

Comment: @FabioMarroni I think he wants to restart the **whole** loop though if I'm reading correctly?

Comment: @Señor O Now that I read it better, I think you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading correctly that you want to restart the **entire** loop when that `if` statement leads to `break`, I think you'll need to create a "wrapper":

```
linhas_title <- c(5, 19, 48, 90, 135, 179, 424, 479, 532)
linhas_url <- c(14, 43, 85, 130, 175, 474, 527, 566)

runAgain = TRUE

while(runAgain)
{
  runAgain = FALSE

  for(i in 1:(length(linhas_title)-1))
  {
    print(paste("Titulo:",i+1, "e", "Url: ", i))

    if(linhas_title[i+1] - linhas_url[i] < 0) 
    {
      print(paste("Titulo", i, "excluido"))
      linhas_title <- linhas_title[-i]
      runAgain = TRUE
      break 
    } 
    else 
      print(paste("Titulos e url pareados!"))
  }

}
```

Comment: What are `true` and `false`?

Comment: @nicola that's a very deep question.

Comment: Exactly! Thanks @SeñorO.

Comment: @SeñorO In R there are `TRUE` and `FALSE`. This is what I meant. Please edit your code; as it is, it doesn't run (unless you defined `true<-TRUE`).

Comment: @nicola - ahhh i see; I've been doing too much C# lately

Comment: @MatheusRabetti no hay de que ;)